# querying viewmodel resulting in error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this problem with querying my viewmodel. I have an index page that displays the posts in a table by showing just the Title, Date and author. When ever a title is clicked it should open up another page displaying the content of that post that is the body of the post. I did this by specifying below in the index page `@Html.ActionLink(item.PostTitle, "ReadTopic", new { PostID = @item.PostID })` and this gives the url `http://localhost:50168/Posts/ReadTopic?PostID=1004`. 
 In the PostsController, I set an actionResult ReadTopic that queries the ViewModel called ListPostVM

```
public class ListPostsVM
    {
        public int PostID { get; set; }

        public string PostTitle { get; set; }


        public string PostContent { get; set; }

        public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
```

and in the controller i set a parameter called PostID so as to query the model based on the query string in  the url that is the PostID so i can retrieve only one post since the ID is unique which means i'm expecting only one result.

```
public ActionResult ReadTopic(int PostID)
{

    var query = from p in db.Post
                 join u in db.User
                 on p.UserID equals u.UserID
                 where p.PostID == PostID
                 select new ListPostsVM()
                 {
                     PostTitle = p.PostTitle,
                     PostContent = p.PostContent,
                     PostDate = p.PostDate,
                     Username = u.Username

                 };
    return View(query);
```

In my view i have this below

```
@model Bloggosphere.ViewModels.PostsComments



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ReadTopic";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>ReadTopic</h2>

       <h1>@Model.PostTitle</h1>
        <p>@Model.PostContent</p>
        <h6>@Model.PostAuthor on @Model.PostDate</h6>
```

Wheneve i click a topic to take me to the ReadTopic View so i can read the body of the title i clicked on i get this error

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Bloggosphere.ViewModels.ListPostsVM]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Bloggosphere.ViewModels.PostsComments'.
```

so i tried another method below

```
@model  IEnumerable<Bloggosphere.ViewModels.PostsComments>




@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ReadTopic";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>ReadTopic</h2>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <h1>@item.PostTitle</h1>
        <p>@item.PostContent</p>
        <h6>@item.PostAuthor on @item.PostDate</h6>
    }
```

this is also resulting in the error below

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Bloggosphere.ViewModels.ListPostsVM]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Bloggosphere.ViewModels.PostsComments]'.
```

Please what am i doing wrong? How can i fix this cos all i want to do is to retrieve a post with that id in the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your query. If you want to get a single post then you should do `First` or `Single` in your query.

```
 var query = from p in db.Post
                 join u in db.User
                 on p.UserID equals u.UserID
                 where p.PostID == PostID
                 select new ListPostsVM()
                 {
                     PostTitle = p.PostTitle,
                     PostContent = p.PostContent,
                     PostDate = p.PostDate,
                     Username = u.Username

                 };
    return View(query.Single());
```

Then in your view you can set your `model` to `ListPostsVM`

```
@model Bloggosphere.ViewModels.ListPostsVM
```

If you want to query multiple tables you can do the following:

```
 var query = from p in db.Post.Where(p => p.PostID == PostID)
             from comments in db.Comments.Where(p => p.PostID == PostID)
                 join u in db.User
                 on p.UserID equals u.UserID
                 where p.PostID == PostID
                 select new ListPostsVM()
                 {
                     PostTitle = p.PostTitle,
                     PostContent = p.PostContent,
                     PostDate = p.PostDate,
                     Username = u.Username
                     Comments = comments
                 };
    return View(query.Single());
```

Comment: thanks. It worked. Lets say i want to display a list of comments that belongs to the post and the relationship between the post and comments is one to many. Do i add the properties i want from the domain model "Comments" to the ViewModel "ListPostsVM". would that mean i would be querying three tables?

Comment: @ibnhamza well, if you want data from multiple tables you either query them separately or do a join, after which you can translate your result into a viewmodel. ViewModel is just a data container it doesn't query anything on its own

Comment: how can i query them seperately and still return the results of the separate queries to one view considering that i want to display the comments that belongs to a post?

Comment: @ibnhamza I've updated my answer with a query that queries multiple tables. Alternatively you can perform multiple joins too

Comment: thanks for the help. Would let you know whatever the result is.